# Cause of CGI process being defunct'ed

Tags: apache, cgi, defunct

I would like to check whether it's possible to trace what time a CGI program gets invoked or ended through any apache logs.

If I am using a javascript to reload a CGI program every 2 seconds and in that CGI program, it checks and does a series of connection to SQL, I wish to find out if the CGI process has already ended by the time my SQL API tries to return a SQL status to that CGI process, thus causing a defunct process?

Will I be able to trace what time a CGI process has ended? What time a CGI process gets invoked through any apache logs?

Need everyone's advice.

Thanks.